# Project build error: Invalid packaging for parent POM [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:[unknown-version], must be "pom" but is "jar"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I create a starter project for spring-boot I get this error in the pom file. This is just to create a basic spring boot project

> Project build error: Invalid packaging for parent POM [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:[unknown-version], must be "pom" but is "jar"

```
<!-- This is the pom which from https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
</project>
```

Comment: Add your pom.xml file in your question

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html i just used the basic pom given here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parent project has `<packaging>JAR</packaging>` not POM. For creating Spring Boot projects with all needed dependencies you can use https://start.spring.io/.

Comment: I checked the parent pom. spring-boot-starter-parent it has packaging as pom.Also I have created several projects from the site but all end up having the same issue

Comment: Do you sit with your machine behind a proxy? then you have to deposit the setting for the proxy in the ide otherwise this does not come out to the mavenrepository. If the error is shown as red cross in pom file, clean the project.

Comment: There is no proxy. I have done that multiple times. I suspect the error is with the maven settings but not sure what it is

Comment: in the above code snippet <packaging>JAR</packaging> is missing, this is the last idea i have

Comment: Thanks for brainstorming on this but this code was generated by spring and not me. I resolved it by deleting the .m2 folder .I spent the whole day on this and this was the answer :-|